# Reading file inside S3 from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-ec2

I would like to use AWS Data Pipeline to start an EC2 instance and then run a python script that is stored in S3.

Is it possible? I would like to make a single ETL step using a python script.

Is it the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and relatively straight forward using Shell Command Activity.

I believe from the details you have provided so far, it seems to be the best way - as DataPipeline provisions the EC2 instance for you ondemand and shuts it down afterwards.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html

There is also a tutorial that you can follow to get acclimated to ShellCommndActivity of Data Pipeline. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-gettingstartedshell.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can direct upload and backup your data in s3

http://awssolution.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-backup-share-and-organize-data.html